# Modify right Margin

Tags: margins, koma-script, classicthesis

I am a newbie using latex to write my CV.

I am using this template

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}} % Font color of your name at the top

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} % Set link colors

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here 

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{Name Sirname}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Education}\vspace{1em}

\NewEntry{2014-present}{XYZ University}

\Description{\MarginText{Bachelor of Engineering}Current GPA: 9.25/10\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ 
\ Department: Electrical and Computer Engineering\newline 
Description: The following year, a specialization in Electronic Electrical and Computer Engineering is intended to be taken.
\newline
Expected Graduation: 2019\newline
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me on how to make the right margin smaller.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code? B.t.w., `\reversemarginpar` does not do what you seem to think: it places margin notes in the left margin instead of placing them  the right margin. Do you use margin notes?

Comment: Don't use `classicthesis` if you do not like the layout it provides. The package makes only sense, if you want exactly the layout it provides. Note also, that using the package with a `scrartcl` results in several warnings, because it breaks several features of the class. If you still want to use the package, you can either use `\recalctypearea` or `\KOMAoption{DIV=calc}` or another setting described in chapter 2 of [`scrguien.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) or load package `geometry` with proper settings somewhere after loading `classicthesis`.

Comment: [The Community edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/373710/2) doesn't make much sense, because the example is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Note that `classicthesis` breaks many features of the KOMA-Script class. So its usage is not recommended.

`classicthesis` uses the KOMA-Script command `\areaset` to define its special text width and height. If you only want to make the right margin smaller you can set `usegeometry` as a class option and then load package `geometry` with option `right=...` after `classicthesis`.

Example with a right margin of `1cm`:

```
\documentclass[
  usegeometry% <- add this option
]{scrartcl}
\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
Text\MarginText{\lipsum[1]}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```